# Show first row if there duplicate and more complicated

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
chat_transcript
id | transcript_id | date 
1  | 123           | 2018-11-04 
2  | 234           | 2018-11-05
3  | 345           | 2018-11-06

chat_message
id | transcript_id | text | author
1  | 123           | a    | null
2  | 123           | b    | Tom
3  | 123           | c    | Paul
4  | 234           | d    | null
5  | 345           | e    | Bryan
6  | 345           | f    | Bryan
```

I want result like this

```
id | transcript_id | date       | text | author
1  | 123           | 2018-11-04 | a    | Tom
2  | 234           | 2018-11-05 | d    | null
3  | 345           | 2018-11-06 | e    | Bryan
```

I want join chat_transcript and chat_message together by transcript_id,
when user send first chat_message, author will be empty till agent send message. But I want to make an API for summary for this chat. I mostly want to grab the first row of each chat(each chat has same transcript_id).
I want to grab id=1,4,5,6.

I know I can do with

```
select distinct on (m.transcript_id)
  *
from chat_transcript as t
join chat_message as m on t.id = m.transcript_id
```

but here is the complicated part, if the author is null, I want to take look other rows which has value. if there is value, I want to replace the value with null value

I found the way to kinda working, but I still feel not quite clean.

```
select distinct on (n.transcript_id)
    t.id, t.date, n.transcript_id, n.text, n.author
form chat_transcript as t
join (
    select
        m.id, m.transcript_id, m.text, a.author
    from chat_message as m
    join (
        select
            t.id, string_agg(distinct m.author, ', ') as author
        from chat_transcript as t
        join chat_message as m on t.id = m.transcript_id
        group by t.id
    ) as a on m.transcript_id = a.id
 ) as n on t.id = n.transcript_id
```

little cleaned up version

```
select distinct on (m.transcript_id)
    nt.id, nt.date, m.index, m.text, nt.author
from chat_message as m
join (
    select
        t.id, t.date, string_agg(distinct m.author, ', ') as author
    from chat_transcript as t
    join chat_message as m on t.id = m.transcript_id
    group by t.id
) as nt on m.transcript_id = nt.id
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please explain the output you want.

Comment: Yes I cannot see any patterns. What should be duplicated? Please explain it a little bit.

Comment: Why do you want `| a    | Tom` and not  `| a    |  null ` or `| b    | Tom`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first message for each transcript, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (t.transcript_id) . . .
from chat_transcript t join
     chat_message m
     on t.transcript_id = m.transcript_id
order by t.transcript_id, m.id;
```